# Customize wsl2 ubuntu terminal prompt

Tags: gnome-terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, prompt

How do I change the ubuntu terminal prompt in of wsl2.
My git-bash prompt looks like this :

[image: Git-bash prompt]

where /Algorithms is the base cwd.
How do I make ubuntu prompt the same, with the same colors?

TIA

Comment: What does `declare -p PS1` output on git bash?

Comment: @muru

declare -x PS1="\\[\\033]0;Git-Bash:\$PWD\\007\\]\\n\\[\\033[32m\\]=> \\[\\033[33m\\]/\\W\\[\\033[32m\\]\`__git_ps1\`\\[\\033[0m\\]\\n\$ "

Comment: Try putting that in your WSL `.bashrc`

Comment: @muru Yes got that, thanks a lot